# Script to compare/contrast two separate Excel files - export differences for both

Tags: excel, vbscript, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, vba

So, today I got a task plopped on my desk and I can't seem to get this script working correctly to complete said task.  My boss gave me two separate .xlsx files with a list of names on both.  She is asking that I find and list which names appear on both excel files, and also find and list which names do not appear on each file individually.

For example

- FileA has Henry and Terry
- FileB has Henry and Samantha
- Generate FileC to show that Henry appears on both FileA and FileB
- Generate FileD to show Terry appears on FileA but not FileB
- Generate FileE to show that Samantha appears on FileB but not FileA

I started with trying to do the first part of pulling a compare list, but I already can't get this to work.  It completes, but It's not exporting right.  All users are listed in both xlsx files in column A.

```bsh
$strReference = Get-Content "C:\Users\person\Desktop\FileA.xlsx"
$strDifference = Get-Content "C:\Users\person\Desktop\FileB.xlsx"
Compare-Object $strReference $strDifference
```

Comment: `Get-Content` is for reading text files. Excel workbooks are not text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest this is the kind of task I wouldn't even consider worthy of writing a script for. Instead, it seems much simpler just to use the =COUNTIF() function on each file, within the Excel worksheet, to check if each name appears in the other one.

So what you'd end up with is a list of people in each file where =COUNTIF(list in other worksheet, person's name) = 1. This is your list of people which are common between both files. You'd also have a number of them where the same COUNTIF = 0, these are your unique entries.

Of course, with names you have to be careful that they're formatted the same, but the work to do this is the same whether you're doing it in VBA or in the worksheet.

Using COUNTIF also has the added bonus that you will spot any duplicates within a worksheet (although you'll spot it against that name, in the other worksheet), should this also be a potential issue.

Comment: This does sound a whole lot easier, I'll give this a shot!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It might be faster to just copy and paste the names from File1 into column A of a new file, 'File3', and paste the names from File2 into column B of File3...then in Column C of File3 you could just do =MATCH(B1,A:A,0) and in Column D of File3 just do =MATCH(A1,B:B,0)...the cells that return values mean you have a match and the cells that give an error do not have a match. I don't think you'd need VBA for this...would that work?

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  Thank you very much!